# Changing RAM from 2 GB up to 4 GB

Tags: windows-vista, memory, performance, operating-systems

I use Windows Vista 32 bit with 2 GB of RAM and now want to increase my RAM of 2 GB up to 4 GB.

Does changing RAM of 2 GB up to 4 GB needs reinstalling windows vista 32 bit? And does 4 GB of RAM needs changing Windows Vista 32 bit to 64 bit?

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not need to reinstall windows.
No, you do not need to change to 64 bit, ***but*** Vista will only be able to use 3.2-3.5gb max. 
For reference: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/windows-vista-basic-ram-limitations/52aaf3f6-157b-4590-9190-7b493f031809